# How to run query to keep maximum 3 rows with the same name

Tags: mysql, sql-update

So I'm trying to run SQL query to deactivate products from listing if there are more then 3 same products (same name - `item_name`) with active state `price_good`. So basically if there are 20 products with the same name and 10 of them are with active state `price_good = 1` the query should disable 7 more of them `price_good = 0` to keep only 3 active products.

The structure of table:

```
id     item_name        price_good
1      Row 1            1
2      Row 1            1
3      Row 1            0
4      Row 1            0
5      Row 1            1
6      Row 1            1
7      Row 1            1
8      Row 1            1
9      Row 2            0
10     Row 2            1
```

The query I'm trying to run:

```
UPDATE ss_remote_inventories t1 
JOIN
  (
    SELECT item_name
      FROM ss_remote_inventories
      WHERE price_good = 1
     GROUP BY item_name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
  ) t2
  ON t1.item_name = t2.item_name
  SET t1.price_good = 0;
```

Comment: Do you have any primary key defined for your table ?

Comment: Yes, ID. Updated the question

Comment: any random 3 ? last 3? first 3?  ..... CR or CoC ?

Comment: Could be any random 3 or first 3 better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following query to update your table to keep first 3 rows for same item

```
update ss_remote_inventories t
join (
  select a.*
  from ss_remote_inventories a
  where a.price_good = 1  
  and (
    select count(*)
    from ss_remote_inventories b
    where a.item_name = b.item_name
    and b.price_good = 1
    and a.id > b.id
  ) > 2
) t1 on t.id = t1.id 
set t.price_good = 0
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ade94/1)

Inner query calculates rank for each row like [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/415318/3) for same item using primary key and in update query it just filters rows who have rank greater than 2 and joins with your main table using id

For updated version 5.7 got it fixed as sub query in  where clause

```
update ss_remote_inventories t
set t.price_good = 0
where id in (
    select id from(
      select a.*
      from ss_remote_inventories a
      where a.price_good = 1  
      and (
        select count(*)
        from ss_remote_inventories b
        where a.item_name = b.item_name
        and b.price_good = 1
        and a.id > b.id
      ) > 2
    ) t1
);
```

[Demo rextester.com/NQEOT48696](http://rextester.com/NQEOT48696)

Comment: `You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause` are you sure its working?

Comment: I see but why it is not working for me? Sorry for the question

Comment: Maybe is MySql version issue?

Comment: @Sandra i am not quite sure if its related to version or other issue

Comment: I'm using the newest one on my production and older one in my localhost. Neither one is working with the following query..

Comment: Doesnt make sense sandra. Can you copy the DEMO code to your system and test it? Because look very good on my side too.

Comment: @Sandra you were right i guess in 5.7 its not working like the 5.6 i have created a demo on http://rextester.com/NQEOT48696 which us based on 5.7 and updated query added in answer